# 100% discount on SKU

Tags: commerce

I've got physical products on my website (specifically vinyl records) that includes a digital download. I've so far used an external download-engine for this but would love to build it into Drupal for user integration reasons.

I want this simple solution. I print download vouchers and insert them in vinyl sleeves. A download voucher includes a 100% discount code valid for one SKU only (the digital version of the lp).

The commerce discount module generates a world of errors on the site, so would like to avoid using that till it's more mature.

Any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: When Commerce Discount fails I always end up writing something custom because I haven't found a decent alternative (yet). Fingers crossed someone's had better luck searching...

Comment: You can do this with discounts and we're working towards a 1.0 release for Commerce Discounts as well as Commerce Coupon.

There isn't an "easy" way to do what you want without Discounts and Coupons. Why isn't Discounts or Coupons working for you?

Comment: after installation my site returned several discount-related errors and the discount admin page resulted in WSOD. I'm currently establish a local development site and will retry once that's in place